# Payment gateway not showing

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon

Good morning folks,

small but very irritating problem. Store2 comes with the Omnipay/Buckaroo payment gateway that's way outdated. Buckaroo switched to a new communication protocol in februari 2014.

The Omnipay github contained the new version and i was able to update this and get it to work for the three payment methods that already showed up in store2.

Then came the problemmy bit, i extended the method to include some functionality not yet implemented in the updated github version. Reason behind this, clients can pay via buckaroo using a few different methods (iDeal, CC, belgium bank, German banks, etc). When you handoff the payment to buckaroo without specifying what to use they show the user a selection screen. Since that selection screen is already part of my site design I need to handoff the payment to Buckaroo with a selector in the request.

**The Omnipay Github version includes 3 methods (iDeal, CC, Paypal). I needed a few extras so i created those. Problem is, their NOT showing up inside Store2.**

Who can point me in the right direction? I've asked the good folkes at DevDemon multiple times but haven't received a response yet (and we're a few weeks down the road already).

With kind regard,
Bas van Ginkel

Updated Omnipay Github
https://github.com/omnipay/buckaroo/tree/master/src

My Github Version
https://github.com/ginkelb/store-buckaroo/tree/master/store_buckaroo/Omnipay/Buckaroo

Answer (score 1):

We resolved this via our internal ticket system:

Omnipay has a “curated” list of supported gateways, if your gateway is not listed, it won’t be loaded.

Open: store/vendor/omnipay/common/composer.json and in the extra/gateways array you will find the supported gateways.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with multiple payment gateways disappearing from the cp as well. What fixed it for me was using PHP 5.3 or lower.

I've been in touch with expresso about this months ago and devdemon only last month. On both occasions I was told it would be looked into.

Comment: WOW, downgrading tot PHP 5.3 or lower is really no option. Going to stalk devdemon again to get this resolved asap. Holding me back on two projects now.